# Find the length of the parametric curve (Difficult)

Tags: integration, parametric

Find the length of the parametric curve

$$x = t$$
$$y = f(t)$$

$$f(t) = \int_0^t {s \over (s^2-1)} \ \mathrm{d}s$$

$$0\leq t \leq 1/2$$

First I create the $x'$and $y'$

Then put it into the formula for parametric curves

$$L = \int_0^{1/2} \sqrt{1^2+{t^2\over (t^2-1)^2}} \ dt$$

Now this is where I'm stuck, I've tried with wolfram alpha and everything but I just can't seem to solve it.

Comment: I suspect there isn't a closed form for this integral. Are you permitted to use a numerical estimate?

Comment: @SimonS Yes but no tools are available, so no computer of any kind. It's supposed to be solved analytically.

Comment: This looks like an incomplete elliptic integral. If so there is no closed form solution and you are going to have to do a numerical estimate. Mathematica gives about 0.418.

Comment: Just a long shot guess, but is it possible your $y$ is missing a factor of $2$? (If so, the arc length radicand is a perfect square, and the integral is straightforward.)

Comment: @user86418 No it's not missing but I think that the question might have a wrong in itself, that it shouldn't be just s over s^2-1 but it's actually supposed to be ds...